# Вывод из базы данных по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, веб-программирование

Есть некоторая форма:

```
<form action="#" class="d-md-flex justify-content-between">
                        <select>
                            <option value="1">Все категории</option>
                            <option value="2">Категория 1</option>
                            <option value="3">Категория 2</option>
                            <option value="4">Категория 3</option>
                            <option value="5">Категория 4</option>
                            <option value="6">Категория 5</option>
                            <option value="7">Категория 6</option>
                            <option value="8">Категория 7</option>
                            <option value="9">Категория 8</option>
                            <option value="10">Категория 9</option>
                        </select>
                        <button type="submit" class="template-btn">Найти</button>
                    </form>
```

Нужно чтобы при выборе раздела "Категория 1" осуществлялся вывод из таблицы 1, если выбрана "Категория 2", то из таблицы 2 и т.д.
Как осуществить такой вывод? Что лучше использовать PHP или JS?

Comment: Штатными средствами JS к базе MySQL не обратиться никак ибо JS-скрипт выполняется в браузере пользователя. Только через серверную часть. Вы можете использовать для этого Node.js или PHP на сервере. Например, написав  AJAX-запрос к PHP-скрипту, который в свою очередь обратится к БД и вернёт результат. А можно обойтись без  JS, отправив обычную форму на сервер.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, поподробнее объяснить, как с помощью php организовать вызов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, я внёс некоторые изменения в HTML-код, ибо считаю что значение оптиона должно отображать его смысл. Соответственно, если категория 1, то и значение оптиона должно быть 1, а не два, как у вас. К тому же, я несколько сомневаюсь в адекватности архитектуры вашего приложения, но тем не менее. Простейший пример без использования JS.

HTML:

```
<form action="your_script.php" class="d-md-flex justify-content-between">
    <select name="category">
        <option value="0">Все категории</option>
        <option value="1">Категория 1</option>
        <option value="2">Категория 2</option>
        <option value="3">Категория 3</option>
        <option value="4">Категория 4</option>
        <option value="5">Категория 5</option>
        <option value="6">Категория 6</option>
        <option value="7">Категория 7</option>
        <option value="8">Категория 8</option>
        <option value="9">Категория 9</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="template-btn">Найти</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

/*
 * Приведённый ниже пример подключения к БД взят из оф. доков PHP
 * Но в реальной жизни мало кто реализует такое подключение к БД.
 * Чаще всего либо делают свою надстройку над классом mysqli, либо используют PDO.
 */
$database = new mysqli("db_host", "db_user", "db_password", "db_name", "db_port");
if ($database->connect_errno)
{
    exit("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $database->connect_errno . ") " . $database->connect_error);
}


// Получаем данные из нашей HTML-формы
$category = $_REQUEST['category'];

// Ниже произведена простейшая проверка на корректность полученных данных
if(!is_numeric($category))
    exit("Category not select!");

/*
 * Так как в вашем примере используется числовое значение номера категории,
 * то для обеспечения безопасности достаточно проверки на числовой тип.
 * Однако в случае с текстовыми данными не забывайте обезопасить себя от
 * SQL-инъекций. =)
 */
$result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `your_table_$category`;");

/*
 * Здесь вы выполняете какие-либо действия с полученным результатом,
 * например, вывод данных на страницу. Всё зависит от того, что вам нужно.
 */
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    /* Выполняем необходимую нам работу */
}

// После завершения работы с результатом запроса, не забудьте очистить память
$result->close();
```

Хотя я не представляю себе, для чего использовать разные таблицы. Если, например, это интернет-магазин, то для разных категорий товара можно было бы использовать одну таблицу, добавив столбец с номером категории. В таком случае запрос в БД выглядел бы так:

```
$result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `cat_id` = $category;");
```

Почему именно так? А потому что при выборе ВСЕХ категорий, составлять запрос на выборку из нескольких таблиц будет немного сложновато. В моём примере `<option value="0">` это "Все категории". Соответственно:

```
/* Не забываем подключиться к БД и получить данные от формы   */

/*
 * Если выбрана НЕ нулевая категория, то заполняем условие выборки по категории
 * иначе оставляем условие пустым
 */
$sql_where = $category != 0 ? " WHERE `cat_id` = $category" : '';

/*
 * Здесь мы ВСЕГДА добавляем значение переменной $sql_where
 * Если она пустая, то будет произведена выбора ВСЕХ значений из таблицы.
 * Если была указана категория, отличная от 1, то переменная будет содержать
 * условие WHERE и данный запрос осуществит выборку указанной категории.
 */
$result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `your_table`$sql_where;");

/* Действия с результатом */
```

Ниже привожу ссылки на оф. документацию PHP, с которой вам следует ознакомиться. А про SQL-инъекции было бы неплохо почитать не столько в доках PHP, сколько погуглить статьи в других источниках.

Полезные ссылки:

1. [MySQLi Quick start guide](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php)
2. [Executing a database query](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
3. [The mysqli_result class](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)
4. [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 2):

Простейший пример с использованием `AJAX`. Для этого создайте отдельный PHP скрипт (например `get_cat.php`), который будет обрабатывать `AJAX` запросы и добавьте на страницу jQuery библиотеку `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<form action="#" class="d-md-flex justify-content-between">
    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="0">Все категории</option>
        <option value="1">Категория 1</option>
        <option value="2">Категория 2</option>
        <option value="3">Категория 3</option>
        <option value="4">Категория 4</option>
        <option value="5">Категория 5</option>
        <option value="6">Категория 6</option>
        <option value="7">Категория 7</option>
        <option value="8">Категория 8</option>
        <option value="9">Категория 9</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

И вот такой JS обработчик

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#category').change(function () {
            var category = $(this).find(':selected').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'get_cat.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {category: category},
                success: (function (data) {
                    //тут необходимые действия (вывод из таблицы в нужный элемент и т.п.) для примера просто выведу информацию в консоль...
                    console.log(data);
                })
            });         
        });
    });
</script>
```

И сам `get_cat.php`

```
<?php
    $hm = 'localhost';
    $db = 'database';
    $un = 'root';
    $pw = 'root';

    $mysqli = new mysqli($hm, $un, $pw, $db);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `category` = '".($_POST['ctegory'])."'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $data = '';
    foreach ($result as $value){
        $data .= #тут строите таблицу, или что вам нужно, в html формате;
    } 
    echo $data;
?>
```

Здесь подразумевается такая же структура таблицы как в ответе выше, т.е. существует поле `category` в таблице БД. Можно использовать запросы из предыдущего ответа в скрипте `get_cat.php`. Можно также вывести результат запроса в JSON массив и отправить ответ в JSON формате и обрабатывать данные в `success` в `AJAX` запросе. Так данные будут динамично обновляться...